# React-portal - Closing a new window using browser close button

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have implemented something similar in my application:

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/mjGvRV?editors=0010

But when I click the browser close button in the new window , "componentWillUnmount" is not being invoked which is why state is not changing even when I close the portal using the browser close button. Is there any solution to this problem? How can I catch the "browser close button" for react portals?

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.win.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing something like this, using `componentDidMount` and 
`componentWillUnmount` to add and remove listeners.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleSomething.bind(this));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleSomething.bind(this));
  }
  handleSomething(event) {
       event.preventdefault();
       this.state.win.close();
  }
```

Comment: thanks. But where is the right place to add this event listener? I have tried it in componentDidMount, render and componentWillUnmount, but didn't work

Comment: tried with your updated answer, but it didn't work. Could you please send me a working codepen link if possible?

Answer (score 0):

In App send closeWindowPortal method as prop to the Window

```
<Window closeWindowPortal={() => this.closeWindowPortal()}>
    <CounterButton />
    <button onClick={() => this.closeWindowPortal()}>Close</button>
</Window>
```

then replace Window component with this

```
class Window extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { win: null, el: null };
    this.hendleClose = this.hendleClose.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let win = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400');
    win.document.title = 'A React portal window';
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    win.document.body.appendChild(el);
    this.setState({ win, el });
    win.onbeforeunload = this.hendleClose
  }

  hendleClose(){
    this.props.closeWindowPortal()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.win.close();
  }

  render() {
    const { el } = this.state;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, el);
  }
}
```